# Before Delete Trigger With Update Other Rows Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I have a table with a foreign key column referencing the same table. This is to do a grouping. I will have one group_master, and then every item in the table that is sufficiently similar to the group_master has a FK referencing that group_master id.

On delete, if the group_master is deleted, I need to update the group to have a new master so I use a Before delete trigger and in the trigger I identify the rows to be updated. Trigger and function code included below.

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION assign_new_group_master() 
        RETURNS TRIGGER
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
        AS
        $$
        DECLARE
            new_group_master details%ROWTYPE;
        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM details WHERE group_master_id = old.id AND old.id <> id) = 0
                THEN RETURN old;
            END IF;
            SELECT * INTO new_group_master
                FROM details
                WHERE group_master_id = old.id AND old.id <> id
                ORDER BY similarity_to_master DESC
                LIMIT 1;
            UPDATE details
                SET group_master_id = new_group_master.id
                WHERE group_master_id = old.id AND id <> old.id;
            PERFORM pg_notify('group_master_id_updated'::Text,row_to_json(new_group_master)::text);
            RETURN old;
        END;
        $$;

        CREATE TRIGGER group_master_deleted_trigger 
        BEFORE DELETE ON details
        FOR EACH ROW
        WHEN (old.id = old.group_master_id)
        EXECUTE FUNCTION assign_new_group_master();
```

This works great when deleting 1 detail element. The problem is if I try to delete many detail elements at 1, it is likely that I am deleting 2 items from the same group which causes this error to be thrown.

```
ERROR:  tuple to be updated was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command 
HINT:  Consider using an AFTER trigger instead of a BEFORE trigger to propagate changes to other rows. 
SQL state: 27000
```

As far as I understand, this is because 1 group_master gets deleted, all its children are updated, then the new group_master gets deleted and so all its children need to be updated again which is not allowed.

How can I get around this issue? I can not change to an After trigger as the hint suggests because then I would be violating the FK constraints of the group_master_id on the children.

Thanks

Comment: do as the error message suggested user an after trigger

Comment: I can not use an after trigger because that would violate the FK constraint on the group_master_id column. I need to first change the FK's of the group members before I delete the group_master.

Comment: why not use a transaction with all three comags, maipulating the table on that the trigger runs will alwas be more than problematic

Comment: This situation mostly is happening due to a cascade delete. Every detail element is a child of another parent element in another table. When that parent is deleted, all the details that are children of that parent get cascade deleted causing this issue.